# ionic invalid key hash facebook does not match any stored

Tags: javascript, android, angular, facebook, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use facebook login it works really well on the browser but on the mobile device ( android ) I get this message

> invalid key hash. the key hash XXXXXXXXXXXXXX doesn't match any stored
>   keys hashes. configure your app key hashes at
>   https://developer.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxxx

I'm sure that I have put the right hash ( I guess ) I did it with those 2 command lines.

**( On Windows Machine )**

First cd to `OpenSSL` directory

`cd C:/openssl/bin`

Second:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I took the key from the console and put it on the facebook developer dashboard android platform!

And I get the above error whatever key I generate!

Comment: don't use Keyhash for Facebook plugin. 
downgrade you FB plugin to v1.7.4. it works without Hashkey.

Comment: You can get facebook hash key by using your system SHA1 fingerprint. Some times we need to use 2 hash keys for android. One is for the device which doesn't have Facebook app (this you can get using SHA1) and second will be for devices which has facebook app installed. For this, you have to

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  We're experiencing this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get facebook hash key by using your system SHA1 fingerprint. Some times we need to use 2 hash keys for android. One is for the device which doesn't have the Facebook app (this you can get using SHA1) and second will be for devices that have facebook app installed. For this, you have to enter the key displayed on the device during the Facebook login error in the app.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't get what are you saying? is there a tutorial or an article explaining these?!

Comment: did you get the fb hash key for your ionic app?

Comment: No, still I can't get it every time gives me a wrong hash key! I ignored the FB login for now on my app! another weird problem that it's working fine on the emulator! another weird thing as well I tried to copy the hash from the error and put on facebook developer console it works but on my phone only! -_-